# App not installed for this user

Tags: applications, adb, uninstallation

I see App in my Apps section of settings which says `App not installed for this user`. It's completely greyed out and I cannot uninstall it. When I install the same from [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osfg.ringtonesetter.main) it says incompatible version is already installed.

I just want to remove this App from my device.

[image]
[image]

Doesn't get uninstalled from adb either

> C:\Users\athakur>adb uninstall com.osfg.rintonesetter.main
>   Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

and

> C:\Users\athakur>adb shell pm uninstall -k com.osfg.rintonesetter.main
>   Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "Reset app preferences" in the same section? You can tap on the three dots shown right beside search icon.

Answer (score 13):

in that App Info (though grey out), click the three vertical dots and use Uninstall for All Users.

Comment: This definitely worked for me, when I saw exactly the greyed-out uninstall button described above.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to uninstall the app,but by doing so the related data will be left over.Here is what you need to do:

1. Go to setting -> apps ->
2. Select the greyed out app (that's the app info section)
3. scroll down to App details at the end and click/tap on it
   this will take you to the play store(the the particular app).
4. Click on install
5. after the installing is finished you would be able to use the app or if you         still want to uninstall it,the go to setting -> apps -> Select the greyed out app-> click/tap on storage ->click/tap clear data and the uninstall the app.

Note if you do not follow the above steps you would'nt be able to "clear data" of the app.

thank you